# DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'DEP6960

Tags: iot, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am working on UWP app, while deploying coming error : DEP6701 : Bootstrapping failed with unexpected error: 'DEP6960 : Source file does not exist: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\14.0\Debugger\target\armv4i\msvsmon.exe'

I am using Visual studio 2015, Raspberry pi 3, Windows 10 core installed in Raspberry pi.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 PC to deploy?

Comment: No, I am using Windows 7 to deploy.

Comment: If you can't find msvsmon.exe in the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\14.0\Debugger\target\armv4i\" try to [install](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#remote-tools-for-visual-studio-2015-update-3) it.

Comment: I have installed "Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3". Then restarted PC. .. still same error. msvsmon.exe doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems related compatibility issues.

Visual Studio 2015(Enterprise, Professional, Community) is supported "**Build only**" on Windows 7 for UWP development.

You can check [Visual Studio 2015 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-compatibility-vs).